# How to get XMLGregorianCalendar to date

Tags: java, xml

In our application we consume a web service which provide the soap response XML(Document Style).

When i checked the web service provider who are just an interface who converts 
the response node value(SubscriberContextIdentifier) which they get from different source into MemberEffectiveTimestamp node and provide the same as response to us.

```
         <SubscriberContextIdentifier>20152201846166</SubscriberContextIdentifier>
```

get converted to MemberEffectiveTimestamp node in the below xml

Response XML sample:

```
                <ct:PersonName>
                <ct:FirstName>MICHAEL</ct:FirstName>
                <ct:Middle1Name>J</ct:Middle1Name>
                <ct:LastName>ROSSMAN</ct:LastName>
        </ct:PersonName>
        <ct:BirthDate>1979-09-10</ct:BirthDate>
        <ct:GenderCode>M</ct:GenderCode>
        <ct:MaritalStatusCode>SNGL</ct:MaritalStatusCode>
        <ct:MemberSequenceNumber>1</ct:MemberSequenceNumber>
        <ct:SmokerStatusCode>UNK</ct:SmokerStatusCode>
        <ct:MemberEffectiveTimestamp>2015-08-08T18:46:16.6Z</ct:MemberEffectiveTimestamp>
        <ct:TimeTracking>
                <ct:UpdateTimestamp>2014-11-08T23:36:48.6</ct:UpdateTimestamp>
                <ct:AsOfDate>2014-11-08</ct:AsOfDate>
        </ct:TimeTracking>
```

Problem:

I need to get back the value which the first provider provided to interface team i.e the SubscriberContextIdentifier from the MemberEffectiveTimestamp

Existing Code:

```
  if (member.getMemberEffectiveTimestamp()!= null) {
        final EntityIdTypeWithChangedAtt.IdValueType idValueType = factory
                .createEntityIdTypeWithChangedAttIdValueType();
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyDDDHHmmssS");
        System.out.println("Memeber Effective Timestamp -->"+member.getMemberEffectiveTimestamp().toGregorianCalendar().getTime());
        System.out.println("Memeber Effective Timestamp after conversion -->"+sdf.format(member.getMemberEffectiveTimestamp().toGregorianCalendar().getTime()));
        idValueType.setValue(sdf.format(member.getMemberEffectiveTimestamp().toGregorianCalendar().getTime()));
        idValueType.setName("SubscriberContextIdentifier");
        idValueLt.add(idValueType);
    }
```

XSD file:

```
   <xsd:element name="MemberEffectiveTimestamp" type="bt:Timestamp"
         minOccurs="0"/>
  <xsd:simpleType name="Timestamp">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:dateTime"/>
```

Output:

```
  Memeber Effective Timestamp -->Sat Aug 08 18:46:16 EDT 2015
  Memeber Effective Timestamp after conversion -->201588184616600
```

Her if you compare the milli seconds value is getting missed out when I retrieve the value from the response xml.

Can anyone now how to convert the XMLGregorianCalendar to date.

Comment: How are the milliseconds getting “missed out”?  The XML element's fractional seconds value is `.6` and your formatted date shows `600` for the milliseconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unable to reproduce the numbers you see, so let me give you the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example):

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xcal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
                                           .newXMLGregorianCalendar("2015-08-08T18:46:16.6Z");
Date date = xcal.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
System.out.println(xcal);
System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyDDDHHmmssSSS").format(date));
```

That prints:

```
2015-08-08T18:46:16.6Z
Sat Aug 08 14:46:16 EDT 2015
2015220144616600
```

As you can see, the time `18:46:16.6Z` is actually `14:46:16 EDT`, not `18:46:16 EDT` as you showed.

Also, you showed a `DDD` value of `88`, when it's really `220`:

```
2015  88 18 46 16 600   <-- from question
2015 220 14 46 16 600   <-- from this answer
```

Why you get `88`, and why it's not zero-prefixed, I don't know.

Also note that `S` is a *millisecond* value, not a fractional second value, and should always be given as `SSS`, otherwise a millisecond value of `.032` will output as `32`, not `032` as it should.

`SimpleDateFormat` cannot output tenth-of-a-second, only millisecond. To get tenth-of-a-second, use `SSS`, then truncate the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an instance of XMLGregorianCalendar, say xcal, then you will get the Date object by calling:

> xcal.toGregorianCalendar().getTime()

But I am not sure whether you'll get the milliseconds from there because they will not be converted to XMLGregorianCalendar.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code :-

First create XMLGregorianCalendar Object

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate = null;
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
gc.setTime(new Date()); 
try{
   xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
}catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then Convert it to Date object

```
/* java.util.Date */
Date date = xmlDate.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
System.out.println("java.util.date :- " + date);
```

You can see complete example [here](http://codedestine.com/convert-xmlgregoriancalendar-to-date/)