# How to get the Date with offset taken into account from XmlGregorianCalendar?

Tags: date, java-6, xmlgregoriancalendar

i have an XMLGregorianCalendar in this form: **2019-06-24T18:18:55.007+02:00**

How can i get the right date (with offset taken into account) in String like this : **24/06/2019 16:18** ?

Comment: Might this be a duplicate of [How to get XMLGregorianCalendar to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36203089/how-to-get-xmlgregoriancalendar-to-date)? Or other previous questions? How thoroughly have you searched?

Comment: Would you want the time in UTC always, or in the user’s time zone?

Answer (score 1):

You tagged your question java-6. Yet I am presenting the modern answer using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. This is available in Java 6 through ThreeTen Backport (see the link at the bottom).

Depending on from where you got your `XMLGregorianCalendar` you may not need to have one. If I understood correctly, this class was used for representing dates and times in XML documents, where they are formatted like for example `2019-06-24T18:18:55.007+02:00`. This format is close enough to ISO 8601 that the classes of java.time can parse it directly, which we prefer:

```
    Locale userLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag("mt-MT"); // Maltese Malta
    DateTimeFormatter displayFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)
                    .withLocale(userLocale);

    String fromXml = "2019-06-24T18:18:55.007+02:00";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(fromXml);
    String formattedUtcDateTime = dateTime.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .format(displayFormatter);
    System.out.println(formattedUtcDateTime);
```

Output from this snippet is (tested in Java 1.7.0_67 with ThreeTen Backport version 1.3.6):

> 24/06/2019 16:18

Assuming that the formatting is for displaying to a user, I recommend using Java’s localized formats. I have chosen Maltese locale because it matches your requested format exactly. If your user is in a different locale, you should still consider the format of that locale.

### Converting from XMLGregorianCalendar

If you got your `XMLGregorianCalendar` from a legacy API that you cannot afford to change just now, there are a number of options for converting it.

One is to get the string back from the `XMLGregorianCalendar`:

```
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlgc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar("2019-06-24T18:18:55.007+02:00");
    String fromXml = xmlgc.toString();
```

Now the rest is as above. Pro: it’s short, and I don’t think there are any surprises in it. Con: To me formatting back into the original string and parsing it once more feels like the detour.

Another option goes through the outdated `GregorianCalendar` class:

```
    GregorianCalendar gc = xmlgc.toGregorianCalendar();
    ZonedDateTime zdt = DateTimeUtils.toZonedDateTime(gc);
    String formattedUtcDateTime = zdt.toOffsetDateTime()
            .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .format(displayFormatter);
```

Pro: I think it’s the official conversion. Con: it’s a line longer, and as I said, it uses the poorly designed and long outdated `GregorianCalendar` class.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Tanks for your answer sir, but it isn't corresponding to a Java 6 Solution, the solution i implemented was getting the Date object 
  from xmlGregorianCalendar : `Date date = xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();`
  then using the getTimeZone method : `int minutesOffset = xmlGregorianCalendar.getTimezone()` (resulting in 120 minutes)
  then `Date wantedDate = date.addMinutes(xmlGregorianCalendar.getTimeZone())` finaly formating to get `24/06/2019 16:18`.

Comment: I haven’t understood which `addMinutes` method you are using? My answer and code will work on Java 6 if you download ThreeTen Backport from [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.threeten%20AND%20a:threetenbp&core=gav) and add the JAR file to your project.

Comment: Is that [`org.joda.time.MutableDateTime.addMinutes`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/MutableDateTime.html#addMinutes-int-)? If so: (1) That’s incorrect/misuse and bound to confuse. (2) The Joda-Time project is in maintenance mode and not recommended for new code. I’d prefer ThreeTen Backport any time. (3) If you insist on Joda-Time, I am sure that a better Joda-Time solution can be found.

Answer (score 0):

The working solution i have found:

```
 private String getFormattedDate(final XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar) {

       Date time = xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
       Date rightDate = DateUtils.addMinutes(time, - xmlGregorianCalendar.getTimezone());
       String formatedDate = DateHelper.format(DateHelper.YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_DASH_COLONS, rightDate);

       return formatedDate;}
```